# Using jquery ajax, datatype:html and I need to get part of coming data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my js function;

```
function getCountryRegions() {
var postData = "id="+$("#selectedCountryId").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/region",
        data: postData,
        dataType:"html",        
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data){
$("#selRegion2").html(data);
$("#selRegion")== $("#selRegion2").html($(data).find("#selRegion"));
}});}
```

The 'data' come exactly like this;

```
<label>Bölge</label>
<select name="selRegion" id="selRegion">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" >-- tümü</option>
      <option value="4140104">Adana</option>
      <option value="4141360">Adrasan</option>
      <option value="4137856">Afyon</option>
</select>"
```

My aim is to get selRegion element and pass it to an Array of Objects. Each object has value and text

I tried this line to make it;

```
$("#selRegion")== $("#selRegion2").html($(data).find("#selRegion"));
```

Comment: What is the error that is happening? What is `selectedCountryId` as called in the ajax call?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with that line. `==` is used for comparing things, but you're not using it in an `if`. What do you mean by "pass it to an array of objects"?

Comment: There is no error ChrisForrence, My ajax gives me data, I need only selRegion inside it. I will take it and put it to an Array.. That's it. SpYk3HH's answer look good. I will try and write the result here.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming through in perfect HTML format, one trick you can use is this:

```
var $data = $("<data />").html(data);
```

Then you can get elements from it like:

```
$data.find("select").each(function(i) { /* DO WORK */ });
```

What this does is create a jQuery Element object Tagged `<data>`.  Thus you're able to act upon it like any other jQuery element like `$("div")` or `$("select")`